# CQ5 Invalid recursion selector value 'data' (data.json.jsp)

Tags: json, adobe, aem, sling

Let's say I have a page in CQ5. I created this page using a template with a single component, call it tableComp, and I hit at url *Test.html*. The component contains its standard JSP file but the page template being used also contains a specific JSP for JSON or XML rendering of custom data, not page data.

This JSP file for rendering would be named something like *data.xml.jsp* or *data.json.jsp*. To hit this rendering JSP for the page *Test.html* you would call */content/{org}/desktop/en_US/{name}/Test.data.json* or */content/{org}/desktop/en_US/{name}/Test.data.xml*.

The XML/JSON JSP would be called which contains code to just get values and print to the screen XML or JSON. Ex: Blah

Now I want to display information to the screen as a JSON output when I hit a new file named *data.json.jsp*. When hitting *data.xml.jsp* it works correctly and hits the JSP. When I do the exact same process for the *data.json.jsp* I then get the following.

```
Invalid recursion selector value 'data' 
Cannot serve request to /content/{org}/desktop/en_US/{name}/Test.data.json in org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

Request Progress:

      0 (2015-07-22 18:10:06) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2015-07-22 18:10:06) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2015-07-22 18:10:06) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/content/{org}/desktop/en_US/{name}/Test.data.json
```

I have tried adding a Pages.json.jsp file to the /libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page section as suggested in another forum but this did not help. The content of this Pages.json.jsp file was <%@include file="proxy.jsp"%>.

How can I get JSON to work for this type of request?

EDIT:

I have changed my original explanation to clarify my problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what output is produced by the xml request and what output you are hoping for with the json request?  Specifically do you want the serialization of the content structure for the entire page or some information about the component itself?

Comment: I updated and revised my question. I am trying to serialize some information about the component itself.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the request is being handled by the `DefaultGetServlet` which in turn uses the [JsonRendererServlet](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/JsonRendererServlet.java) to process your requests with `.json` extensions.

Since the JsonRendererServlet requires a numeric selector or the `infinity` selector, it throws the following error.

> Invalid recursion selector value `<<selector>>`

However requesting `/Test/_jcr_content.data.json` would render the JSON data processed by the `data.json.jsp` instead of the `DefaultGetServlet`.

Comment: Calling this URL does not render anything on the page. It just shows a white page.

Comment: Do you mean /content/{org}/desktop/en_US/{name}/Test/_jcr_content.data.json just shows a white page? Can you provide additional info regarding your data.json.jsp because the above works fine in my AEM instance.

Comment: I updated and revised my original question. I am not trying to get a json representation of the page. I am trying to hit a json.jsp file to output custom JSON.

Comment: Actually, the answer which i provided calls your json.jsp and then provides you its output. But if you are saying that it shows a blank page, check if there is some error that is being while processing the json.jsp